# how to position svg which is nested and contained in parent svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

```html
<svg width="33.5cm" height="57.5cm" style="border:1px solid black;">
  <svg width="31.8cm" height="54cm" x="1cm" y="2cm" style="border:1px solid black;">
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:none;"/>
   
   <!-- Header -->
   <svg width="100%" height="5.8cm">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:none;"/>
    
    <!-- Logo -->
    <svg width="23.6cm" height="100%">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:none;"/>
    
    </svg>
   </svg>
   
   <!-- body -->
   <svg width="100%" height="20.6cm" transform="translate(0cm,5.8cm)">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:3; fill:none;"/>
    
   </svg>
   
   <!-- Ad -->
   <svg width="100%" height="26.8cm">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:none;"/>
    
   </svg>
  </svg>
 </svg>
```

i'm working on svg in html and added some nested svg in the webpage. how can I position the child svg contents which are present in a parent svg? the x and y coordinate is not working. and also tried translate but it is not working. I want to give values in cm (I don't know how to do it), but values in px also not working. is there a way to position svgs relative to one another? or if not possible, how can I translate or position it manually?
The code is in sniplet, kindly check it out

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me? `Firefox 53.0.2`

Comment: code is working, but positioning is not how it should be. the body svg should be 5.8cm below, but its not in this case

Comment: the values in pixels are working in firefox, but cm is not working there too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `x` and `y` attributes to position nested `<svg>` elements.  For example:

```
<!-- body -->
<svg width="100%" height="20.6cm" x="0" y="5.8cm">
```

In the example below I have used this method to position the body svg.  I also made it red here so it is obvious which one it is.

```html
<svg width="33.5cm" height="57.5cm" style="border:1px solid black;">
  <svg width="31.8cm" height="54cm" x="1cm" y="2cm" style="border:1px solid black;">
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:none;"/>
   
   <!-- Header -->
   <svg width="100%" height="5.8cm">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:none;"/>
    
    <!-- Logo -->
    <svg width="23.6cm" height="100%">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:none;"/>
    
    </svg>
   </svg>
   
   <!-- body -->
   <svg width="100%" height="20.6cm" x="0" y="5.8cm">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:3; fill:red;"/>
    
   </svg>
   
   <!-- Ad -->
   <svg width="100%" height="26.8cm">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1; fill:none;"/>
    
   </svg>
  </svg>
 </svg>
```

**Note** Be aware that a "cm" in SVG units will almost certainly not correspond to a real-world cm - for example on screen or printed.  SVG units like "cm" and "in" are based on a standard CSS DPI of 96 CSS pixels per inch.  No attempt is made to match the real DPI of the device that the SVG is being rendered on.